# Is this possible to find equation of a series using genetic programming?

Tags: algorithm, math, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, series

I have a list of numbers which form a series. I want to find the equation which can regenerate the same series. Is this possible? Also, what would you recommend to program it (GA, GP, etc). Please give an example.

Comment: I would chose a parametric form for the series, allow for some noise (if pertinent) and try to fit the parameters with eg. least square, more general maximum likelihood or even Bayesian. If your numbers are integer numbers, please don't take what I said into account.

Comment: @Alexandre: You would still need something to fit _with_, e.g. a formula where there are parameters to be estimated.

Comment: @Tim: that is what "parametric form" means. There is no way out, you *have* to make assumptions if you want the result to be useful. Otherwise, you will trivially overfit the series. Also it would help if the OP told us what he wants to do with the equations he looks for. If the goal is compression of data, there are other ways to do it. If the goal is modelling, then parametric forms are compulsory.

Comment: You have been a member of Stack Overflow for 8 months now, but never voted and never accepted an answer. Please read the FAQs!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may take a look at [**project Eureqa**](http://ccsl.mae.cornell.edu/eureqa) [image]

> Eureqa (pronounced "eureka") is a software tool for detecting equations and hidden mathematical relationships in your data. Its goal is to identify the simplest mathematical formulas which could describe the underlying mechanisms that produced the data. Eureqa is free to download and use.

The software is designed to find least squares approximations for series of data. If your series can be exactly described as a function, you'll probably find it.  Eureqa uses genetic algorithms, and in the web page there are a few references to papers and articles.

Below you may see the results (from my machine) for a series formed as 3*x^2+4 running on Eureqa:

[image]

#### Post Scriptum:

Regrettably the software isn't free anymore :(

Comment: Thanks for replying. What should I do if I have guess that these constants can be involved in generating the serires. For Example: today's date, day of birth etc... How can I add these constants in the equation.

Comment: @Nabeel You have to download the software and then load all your variables as columns in an excel-type spreadsheet. After that you select what kind of functions you want to use (ie. trig, exponentials, polynomials, etc), and the software recombine those "master" functions using genetic algs till it finds a match